# Schrödinger's Equation with multi-part potential

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, potential

I have this potential

$$V(x) =
\left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
  \infty  & \mbox{if } x < -a \\
  \frac{V_o}{a}x & \mbox{if } -a \leq x \leq a \\
       V_o & \mbox{if } x \geq a \
 \end{array} 
\right.$$

And I want to know, qualitatively, how the wave function would look like.

So, the particle cannot live at the left of the "wall" at $x=-a$, so the wave fucntion there is $0$. To the left of the ramp (i.e., for $x>a$), the potential is constant, so the particle will behave like a free one. Namely, the wave function will be constant in that zone.

But what happens in the middle? I'm not interested in the mathematical approach for this, I've already looked it up and it seems to be related with Airy functions or something like that. However, I want to *understand* what would happen, not just do the math. I think that the wave function in this zone will depend on the value of $E$ the particle has.

This is what I thought: for low values of energy, the particle will have a small probability of getting trough the ramp (tunneling?); on the other hand, for high values of energy ($E>V_o$ I suppose), the probability of the particle living in the zone with the constant potential would be higher, as the "box" in the middle wouldn't be able to contain it.

My guess is that if $E<V_o$ the wave function would look like a sine wave atenuated along the $x$-axis until it reaches $x=a$, where it would become constant. If $E>V_o$, it would be the same but with the sine wave increasing its amplitude this time.

Is this reasoning correct? Or any other form of thinking about it?

Comment: A point for pedants like me: You're not interested in how a wavefunction would look, you're interested in how an *energy eigenstate* would look.

Comment: (Pedants)^2 would say that you are interested in the *wavefunction of the energy eigenstates*.  :)

Comment: You're a little backwards in your reasoning, but you're on the right track.   For $x>a$ you say the wave function will increase in amplitude.    Think about normalizing that function.  Once you get on the right track, you will notice that your picture for $E<v_0$ is not correct.

Comment: I'd say the obvious first step is to solve the equation using the Airy functions, plot it, and see whether your intuition was right. Did you try that?

Comment: @garyp I meant that for $x>a$ the function will be constant; the increasing-amplitude thing would happen just between $-a$ and $a$. And yes, it would  be non-normalizable there, but I don't see how that could help :/

Comment: @DavidZ I thought of doing that but I should have to find the right constants to satisfy the contour conditions and I don't even know how to derive an Airy function (I've never heard it before :P), so I went this way

Comment: Well then, you are not on track.  (Aside: there is no tunneling possible.)   You mention a constant wave function.  What potential creates a constant wave function?   Also, you are not correctly analyzing what happens when $x>a$ and $E<V_0$.   Try to sort out that last point, perhaps by studying what happens to a finite square well potential.  In fact, I recommend that you carefully study the finite square well before proceeding.

Comment: @garyp Sorry, I mixed up the terms. I meant a constant probability function ($\Psi^{*}\Psi$)

Comment: @Tendero: $\psi(x)^*\psi(x)$ is not a probability. It's a probability *density* distribution. $\psi(x)^*\psi(x)$ does not give you the probability in the point $x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Qualitatively*, the wave functions of the *bound states* in a triangular potential well like the one you described, look like this:

[image: Triangular well]

For $x<-a$, $\psi=0$ because of the infinite potential in that region.

Where the wave function crosses the potential line, quantum tunnelling occurs and $\psi \to 0$.

For particle energies above $V_0$, no bound states can exist (these so called *scattered states* are not shown).

The triangular potential well can be seen as a crude approximation of the [Morse potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morse_potential#Potential_energy_function).

Comment: Please do not post complete solutions!

Comment: @garyp: this is hardly a complete solution. That would take some seriously hard calculations. I have the solutions somewhere but won't post them.

Comment: It's nearly a complete answer to his question.  Remember he or she said " I'm not interested in the mathematical approach for this"  I will grant that you didn't include the $E>V_0$ case, so that does leave something for the OP to think about.

Comment: In that graph, $\psi$ would be the probability function, right? Not the eigenstate itself, but the product of it with its conjugate

Comment: @Tendero: No, $\psi$ is the wave function *of the eigenstate*. For *probability density distributions*, take $\psi^*\psi$ for Complex $\psi$, or $\psi^2$ for Real $\psi$ (provided the wave functions have been normalised).

Comment: I don't see why it is constant for $x>a$ then. Isn't the solution there the same for a free particle (a complex exponential)?

Comment: *I don't see why it is constant for $x>a$ then* Nobody says it is. $\psi$  goes to **zero** for $x \to +\infty$. In that region, $\psi$ is a decaying exponential function, something like $\psi=ae^{-\lambda x}$.

Comment: Also take garyp's suggestion to heart: study the particle in a 1D rectangular well. Very insightful and much to be learned there! Thanks for the upvote.